# Best way to draw a grid with colored squares using FuncAnimation

Tags: python, matplotlib

So I am trying to make a game of life using matplotlib's FuncAnimation function to update the grid I am displaying. However, the process is taking longer and longer, probably because I am not pointing out what I am updating. I am not very familiar with the concept of artists either.

For the moment, my code looks like this :

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.colors
import random as rd
import matplotlib.animation as animation
from time import process_time


Ln = 100     # length
La = 10     # width

data = np.ones((Ln, La)) * np.nan   # matrix filled with 0 containing the squares to be colored
pause = False       # puts in pause when clicking
Case = [(i, j) for i in range(Ln) for j in range(La)] # squares of the grid
Case = dict(zip([i for i in range(La*Ln)], Case))


def randometre(a):

    '''
    Colors a square.
    '''

    while Case:
        if not pause:
            xx, yy = Case.pop(rd.choice(list(Case.keys())))       # colors the next square in a random order
            data[xx, yy] = 1    # square that is being colored
            ax.fill_between([xx, xx + 1], [yy], [yy + 1], color=C)
        break   # to see the coloring process
    return


def on_click(event):
    global pause
    pause ^= True

# random color generation
C = '#%02X%02X%02X' % (rd.randint(0,255), rd.randint(0,255), rd.randint(0,255))

xx = 0
yy = 0


# plotting
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', on_click)

# drawing grid and squares
for y in range(La + 1):
    ax.plot([0, Ln], [y, y], lw=2, color='k')
for x in range(Ln + 1):
    ax.plot([x, x], [0, La], lw=2, color='k')



# loop coloring squares
ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, randometre, blit=False, interval=10, repeat=False, frames=La*Ln)
ax.axis('off')
plt.show()
```

So what I need is the fastest way to color the squares as well as being able to see the progress live without slowing down.
A similar issue has been raised [here](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/6985/) but I can't manage to adapt it to my code unfortunately...

Thank you very much for your time and help !

Answer (score 0):

You should use `blit=True`, I did two modifications to your code. Now is fast.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.colors
import random as rd
import matplotlib.animation as animation
from time import process_time


Ln = 100     # length
La = 10     # width

data = np.ones((Ln, La)) * np.nan   # matrix filled with 0 containing the squares to be colored
pause = False       # puts in pause when clicking
Case = [(i, j) for i in range(Ln) for j in range(La)] # squares of the grid
Case = dict(zip([i for i in range(La*Ln)], Case))


def randometre(a):

    '''
    Colors a square.
    '''

    while Case:
        if not pause:
            xx, yy = Case.pop(rd.choice(list(Case.keys())))       # colors the next square in a random order
            data[xx, yy] = 1    # square that is being colored
            poly = ax.fill_between([xx, xx + 1], [yy], [yy + 1], color=C)
        break   # to see the coloring process
    return poly, # must return something to make blit=True to work


def on_click(event):
    global pause
    pause ^= True

# random color generation
C = '#%02X%02X%02X' % (rd.randint(0,255), rd.randint(0,255), rd.randint(0,255))

xx = 0
yy = 0


# plotting
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', on_click)

# drawing grid and squares
for y in range(La + 1):
    ax.plot([0, Ln], [y, y], lw=2, color='k')
for x in range(Ln + 1):
    ax.plot([x, x], [0, La], lw=2, color='k')



# loop coloring squares, blit=True
ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, randometre, blit=True, interval=10, repeat=False, frames=La*Ln)
ax.axis('off')
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help ! But the problem is that the colored squares don't stick around, they don't remain colored. So is it not possible with `blit=True` ?
If you run and plot my code, you can see that in the end, all squares get colored but it is just getting slower and slower...